# how is a macro expanded in clojure?

Tags: macros, clojure, expand

In the book Programming Clojure(Stuart), when read how macros are expanded I got confused.

```
user=> (defmacro chain
          ([x form] (list '. x form))
          ([x form & more] (concat (list 'chain (list '. x form)) more)))
#'user/chain
```

The above macro can be expanded as:

```
user=> (macroexpand '(chain a b c))
(. (. a b) c)
```

But the following is only expanded to the first level:

```
user=> (macroexpand '(and a b c))
(let* [and__3822__auto__ a]
     (if and__3822__auto__ (clojure.core/and b c) and__3822__auto__))
```

The ***and*** macro source:

```
user=> (source and)
(defmacro and([] true)
    ([x] x)
    ([x & next]
    `(let [and# ~x]
          (if and# (and ~@next) and#))))
```

Why is the ***chain*** macro expanded all the way but the ***and*** not ? Why is it not  expanded to something like the following:

```
user=> (macroexpand '(chain a b c d))
(. (chain a b c) d)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`macroexpand` expands the outermost form over and over until it gets a non-macro result. If you want to see just the output of a single phase of macroexpansion, use `macroexpand-1`.

So the difference is, `chain`'s recursive call is first, and `and`'s is not.

Answer (score 2):

To me, amalloy's response directly answers your question. However, if veiled beneath your question, you are wondering how to show the fully macroexpanded form of something, I would point you in the direction of [clojure.walk](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/1.3.0/clojure.walk)'s [`macroexpand-all`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/1.3.0/clojure.walk/macroexpand-all). Using your same example, now with macroexpand-all:

```
user=> (macroexpand-all '(and a b c))
(let* [and__3546__auto__ a]
  (if and__3546__auto__
    (let* [and__3546__auto__ b]
      (if and__3546__auto__ c and__3546__auto__))
    and__3546__auto__))
```

All macros have been expanded. Also notice that for your first example, it will behave the same as `macroexpand` (for the reasons amalloy gave):

```
user=> (macroexpand-all '(chain a b c))
(. (. a b) c)
```